# telegram editMessageMedia alternative for telepot

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

python's telepot library is no longer being maintained and updated
in new telegram bot api update editMessageMedia was added

how to use it with http GET/POST request ?
( requests library or any other lib )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the endpoint by sending a request via `requests` like this but note that there are various maintained bot libraries out there you can utilize.

```
import requests
import json

BOT_TOKEN = ' ... '
CHAT_ID = ...
MESSAGE_ID = ...

files = {
    'media': open('./photo.jpg', 'rb'),
}

media = json.dumps({
    'type': 'photo',
    'media': 'attach://media'
})

message = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/editMessageMedia?chat_id={CHAT_ID}&message_id={MESSAGE_ID}&media={media}"

result = requests.post(message, files = files)

print(result.json())
```

set the values for `CHAT_ID`, `MESSAGE_ID` and `BOT_TOKEN`. Also, update `'./photo.jpg'` with the path to the new file.

One last thing if the media you are trying to edit is not photo (audio and other files), update the line `'type' : 'photo'` as well. (check out https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmedia for details)

Comment: is it possible to edit the photo only while keeping the caption?